# How to replace Qualify key word in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, teradata

What is the qualify equivalent in BigQuery. The TD query I have is below and I m trying to form a equivalent BQ

```
select cast(pol.ORDER as int) as target
  from db.porder po
  inner join db_line pol
    on po.po_nbr = pol.po_nbr
    and po.order_date = pol.order_date
qualify row_number() over (partition by po.po_nbr order by po.order_date desc) = 1
  where 
  po.po_nbr = '12345'
  and pol.LINE_NBR = 1
```

Comment: The `qualify` equivalent is `qualify`.  You need to fix your query so the `where` is before the `qualify`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your query works in TD - try below in BQ

```
select cast(pol.ORDER as int) as target
  from db.porder po
  inner join db_line pol
    on po.po_nbr = pol.po_nbr
    and po.order_date = pol.order_date
  where 
  po.po_nbr = '12345'
  and pol.LINE_NBR = 1
  qualify row_number() over (partition by po.po_nbr order by po.order_date desc) = 1
```

See about [QUALIFY clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause) in BQ